# evaluating variable and assigning to another variable in one line

Tags: lua

I have a variable that's returned from the db as a string.  I convert it to a number and then test like so:

```
        if tonumber(v.active) == 1 then
           elements.active.value = true
        else
           elements.active.value = false
        end
```

The value in elements.active.value is being used to diplay a checkbox.  I'm wondering if there's a way to combine this all into one statement?

**EDIT 1**

I'm using a lua boolean value to set the checkbox, so I can't use 1.  You have to use true / false.
I'm not so much interested in whether or not I can use 1 or true to set the value.  I'm more interested in keeping the logic the same, but simplifying.

What I was really after was something like what you can do in php like so:

```
max = array_key_exists ('max', $options) ? $options['max'] : 0;
```

it'll use either the $options['max'] value or 0 depending on the eval.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
elements.active.value = tonumber(v.active) == 1
```

Because the result of a relational operator like `==` is boolean, just what you assigned to `elements.active.value` in your piece of code.

> #### [Lua reference manual: Relational Operators](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.3)
>
> The relational operators in Lua are
>
> ```
> ==    ~=    <     >     <=    >=
> ```
>
> These operators always result in `false` or `true`.

Comment: I guess I assumed lua would treat "true" as different from 1.  maybe a bad assumption.  going to test now.

Comment: ok... so I definitely can't just use 1.  I have to evaluate it to translate 1 into true so that my form displays checkbox correctly.   So... your answer doesn't work.

Comment: Yes but when you are using the value to display a checkbox, it doesn't work.  I'll hunt around to see if there's something else going on...

Comment: @dot `true` is different from `1`. But here the expression `tonumber(v.active) == 1` has the value of either `true` or `false`. I'm assigning this boolean value to `elements.active.value`. How did you test? Try this: `a = 1; v = a == 1; print(v)`, doesn't it output `true`?

Comment: Yu, I think I found a bug in the framework that I'm using.  When I set the vaue to "true" and do a view source, the html looks exactly the same as if I set the value to 1.  BUT... the page doesn't show the checkbox when you just use 1.

Comment: @dot I don't know your framework. All I know is that the one-liner in my answer is **equivalent** to the piece of code in your question. If you think so now, remove your downvote.

Comment: I agree.  I'm just new to lua but familiar with other programming languages.  Thought it was a lua thing that the 1 wasn't working.  But I'm now thinking it's a bug in the framework.   So assuming I have to keep all the code I have to work around the bug, do you have any suggestions for simplifying the code?

Comment: @dot If you are sure it's a bug, then how can you be sure any other simplifying won't trigger the bug? So I don't know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41647/discussion-between-dot-and-yu-hao)

Comment: i think its more realted to the fact that i'm using a lua boolean value to set the checkbox as checked or not.  so can't use 1.  must use true